# Using batch to controll my network adapters

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, goto

I'm trying to write a simple batch file that will ask me if i want to enable or disable my network adapter, and then pass my answer on to netsh. (I like to turn it off when watching Netflix on my TV, seems to help quality)

I've written this:

```
set /p %letter%=[(E)nable or (D)isable:]
IF %letter=="e". goto enable
IF %letter=="d". goto disable

:enable
set command=enable
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=%command%
Pause
exit

:disable
set command=disable
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=%command%
pause
exit
```

But the "goto's never seem to get followed. it always picks the first subroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the % around the variable in the set command too:

```
:again
set /p letter=[(E)nable or (D)isable:]
IF /i "%letter%"=="e" goto enable 
IF /i "%letter%"=="d" goto disable
echo D or E please!
goto again
```

The strings in each side of the `==` must exactly match. The `/i` switch makes the comparison case-insensitive. If neither matches, then the next line is executed - hence always going to `enable`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
@echo off
set /p letter=[(E)nable or (D)isable:]
IF /i "%letter"=="d"     ipconfig /release *
IF /i "%letter"=="e"     ipconfig /renew
```